# Why Open API Generator generates methods with underscore?

Tags: java, maven, openapi-generator-maven-plugin

I am using Open API Generator with Java Maven Plugin

When I build the project, it generates two methods, one with the annotation and the other for us to override. Why can't it be a single one instead? Is anything configured wrong?

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
    <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${openapi-generator-maven-plugin.version}</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <inputSpec>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/openapi.yaml</inputSpec>
                <generatorName>spring</generatorName>
                <apiPackage>club.allin.api</apiPackage>
                <modelPackage>club.allin.models</modelPackage>
                <skipValidateSpec>false</skipValidateSpec>
                <strictSpec>true</strictSpec>
                <generateApiDocumentation>true</generateApiDocumentation>
                <removeOperationIdPrefix>true</removeOperationIdPrefix>
                <configOptions>
                    <useTags>true</useTags>
                    <delegatePattern>true</delegatePattern>
                    <interfaceOnly>true</interfaceOnly>
                    <removeOperationIdPrefix>true</removeOperationIdPrefix>
                </configOptions>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

It generates something like that

```java
@GetMapping
default ResponseEntity<ResponseObject> _getSpendings(){
   return getSpendings();
}

//Override this method
default ResponseEntity<ResponseObject> getSpendings(){
   return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_IMPLEMENTED);
}
```

Why does it generate two methods? Can I configure to be only one?

[printscreen image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IDqFj.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are setting `<delegatePattern>true</delegatePattern>`, just set it to false or remove it (default value is false) if you don't need it and you will get a single method. I encountered troubles with delegate pattern when I tried to trigger an aspect for controller method and it did the trick as well.